# File_put_contents: Replacing <pre> with newline in the output .txt file

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the source of remote page then write it to a .txt file, the source is a series of set of characters in between the `<pre>` . eg. `<pre>fdnssnbsfsjgjka5d7</pre>`
i want to write each in a new line in the txt file, i tried :

`$url = 'remote page';
    $file = '1.txt';
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $page = str_replace(array('<pre>','</pre>'),array('','/n'),$doc->saveHTML());
    file_put_contents($file, $page);`

but no working and got the source unformatted in the txt file

Comment: Try array('','\n') instead Or array('','\r\n')

Comment: `'\n'` will be the literal characters `\ ` and `n` as you're enclosing them in single quotes. `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL` will be a new line.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com not working instead it echo \r\n in the file itself

Comment: @h2ooooooo also echo /n or PHP_EOL in the txt file

Comment: @sherifhalim Do not use single quotes. `'\n'` is not the same as `"\n"`. `'PHP_EOL'` and `"PHP_EOL"` is not the same as `PHP_EOL` (no quotes as it's a constant). `/n` is not the same as `\n`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo here its ` $page = str_replace(array('<pre>','</pre>'),array('','"PHP_EOL"'),$doc->saveHTML());
` and still show in my file as "PHP_EOL"

Comment: Like I said, `PHP_EOL` is a constant - it should not be inside quotes. `'"PHP_EOL"'` is not the same as `PHP_EOL`. `'PHP_EOL'` is not the same as `PHP_EOL`. `"PHP_EOL"` is not the same as `PHP_EOL`. `array('', PHP_EOL)`.

Answer (score 0):

'/n' will show /n in your page. You can simply use PHP_EOL constant.
If you don't want to use PHP_EOL, use "\n" or "\r\n"  instead, with double quotes (these let PHP convert \r and \n in CR and LF) and a backslash.

NB: In your example, you can directly jump from the file_get_contents() to the str_replace unless you perform some operations not shown here.

Comment: "\r\n" also show in file, how to use PHP_EOL with str_replace

Comment: You're sure to use "double" instead of 'single' quote? If it's the double ones, you must have something converting `CRLF` into `\r\n`.

To use PHP_EOL `str_replace(['<pre>', '</pre>'], ['', PHP_EOL], $html)`